# How to use API Winspool.EnumprinterData in Delphi?

Tags: api, delphi

Does anyone have experience with using the `Winspool.EnumprinterData` API in Delphi?

I found a demo for C++:
 https://s-kita.hatenablog.com/entry/20120227/1330353801

I tried to covert it to Delphi as below:

```
procedure TForm1.GetPrinterData;
var
 hPrinter  : THandle;
 pInfo:  PPrinterInfo2;
 bytesNeeded: DWORD;
 dwRet : DWORD;
 dwIndex: DWORD;
 pValueName: PWideChar;
 pTagName: PWideChar;
 cbValueName: DWORD;
 pcbValueName : DWORD;
 pType: DWORD;
 pData: PByte;
 cbData: DWORD;
 pcbData: PDWORD;
 i : Integer;
 printername : String;
 dwValueNameSize : DWORD;
 dwDataSize : DWORD;
 begin
   hprinter := GetCurrentPrinterHandle;
   dwRet := EnumPrinterDataw(hprinter,i,nil,0, pcbValueName,pType,nil,0,pcbData);
 end;
```

Question 1: `EnumPrinterDataW` result is not the same, even if I chose the same printer, and it often raises an Access Violation error.

Question 2: the API has many pointer type variables, the next step should allocate memory to some variable, but I do not know how to do thqt. For example `pData: PByte; Pdata = Allocmem(pcbData^);` <==== this is difficult to me, `Pdata` is `TByte`, how to `allocmem(pcbData^)` is `TPwidechar` how to do this?

This has taken me 2 days to deal with, and it is still a mess !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code:

- you are not checking if `GetCurrentPrinterHandle()` returns a valid printer handle.
- you are not initializing your `i` variable.  You need to pass a 0-based index to `EnumPrinterData()`, but the value of `i` is *indeterminate*.
- you are not initializing your `pcbData` variable.  `EnumPrinterData()` expects a pointer to a `DWORD` variable that will receive the size of the data written to the `pData` buffer (or the needed size of the `pData` buffer if `pData` is nil).  But your `pcbData` is not pointing to a valid `DWORD`.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.GetPrinterData;
var
  hPrinter: THandle;
  dwIndex,
  dwRet,
  dwType,
  dwMaxValueNameSize,
  dwMaxDataSize,
  dwValueNameSize,
  dwDataSize: DWORD;
  pValueName,
  lpData: array of Byte;
  sValueName: UnicodeString; // or WideString in D2007 and earlier
begin
  hPrinter := GetCurrentPrinterHandle;
  if hPrinter = 0 then
    Exit; // or raise an exception

  try
    dwIndex := 0;

    dwRet = EnumPrinterData(hPrinter, dwIndex, nil, 0, dwMaxValueNameSize, dwType, nil, 0, @dwMaxDataSize);
    if dwRet = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS then
      Exit
    else if dwRet <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
      RaiseLastOSError(dwRet);

    SetLength(pValueName, dwMaxValueNameSize);
    SetLength(pData, dwMaxDataSize);

    repeat
      dwValueNameSize := 0;
      dwDataSize := 0;

      dwRet = EnumPrinterData(hPrinter, dwIndex, PWideChar(pValueName), dwMaxValueNameSize, dwValueNameSize, dwType, PByte(pData), dwMaxDataSize, @dwDataSize);
      if dwRet = ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS then
        Exit
      else if dwRet <> ERROR_SUCCESS then
        RaiseLasstOSError(dwRet);

      SetLength(sValueName, PWideChar(pValueName), (dwValueNameSize div SizeOf(WideChar)) - 1); // -1 for null terminator

      // use dwType, sValueName, and pData up to dwDataSize bytes, as needed...

      Inc(dwIndex);
    until False;
  finally
    // only if GetCurrentPrinterHandle returns a handle that needs to be closed now...
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your great great help! 
But have more questions, need your help. (sorry, I'm not good at English)

Q1. in your answer :
    SetLength(sValueName, PWideChar(pValueName), (dwValueNameSize div SizeOf(WideChar)) - 1); // -1 for null terminator

```
I dont understnt this SetLength format.....and complier raise an Error :
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(111): E2008 Incompatible types
```

Q2. how to get  value :
    sValueName ----> ValueName : array of Byte, how to get string value form an array of Byte

sorry for my poor ability. I really do not get pointer type Data, need more study

Comment: Hi Remy Lebeau:
  I should add a comment in your answer. not add a new answer, my bad!!!